# Why Dead code warning

Tags: java, android

I have dead code warning at this position:

```
if("Email" == "+email.getText().toString()+"){
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "email_id already available ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the warning?

Comment: First use equals for comparing Strings instead of `==`

Answer (score 4):

> if("Email" == "+email.getText().toString()+")

**"Email"** can never be equal to **"+email.getText().toString()+"**

You probably wanted to write

```
if("Email" == email.getText().toString())
```

and you should use the **equal-Method** to compare Strings:

```
if("Email".equals(email.getText().toString()))
```

You'll find more informations about comparing Strings in Java [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: yep it would work. but it definitely is bad code. you should use equal to compare Strings or Objects in java

Answer (score 4):

"Email" will never be equal to "+email.getText().toString()+". I think you wanted to use:

`if ("Email".equals(email.getText().toString()))`

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
 if("Email".equals(mail.getText().toString()))
    {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "email_id already available ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `"Email" == "+email.getText().toString()+"` with `"Email".equals(email.getText().toString())`

Strings should always be compared using the `equals()` method.'

Also, consider defining constants, e.g.

```
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email"
```

then use

```
if(email.getText().toString().equals(KEY_EMAIL)) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
if(email.getText().toString().equals("Email"){ 
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "email_id already available ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}
```

or use ignoreCaseEquals, explanation why it is dead code you must know by now by reading above answers