# Android list of folders, skip folders by names

Tags: android, directory

What is wrong here?

```
 for (File f: list){

      Log.e("dir", f.getName());

      String foldername = f.getName().trim();
      if(foldername != "Test"){
      Log.e("dir_repeat",foldername);
      }
 }
```

Why do I receive **dir_repeat** even when the folder name is ***Test*** ??

I want to skip some folders while list, based on their names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check `String` like this using `equals()`

```
for (File f: list){
      Log.e("dir", f.getName());
      String foldername = f.getName().trim();
      if(foldername.equals("Test"))
      {
        Log.e("dir_repeat",foldername); 
      }
}
```

see this link [Why Dead code warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615314/why-dead-code-warning/30615394#30615394)